# Elegant way to code partially copy objects in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have a javascript object that represents form fields. about 70% of these fields have to be copied in some objects for sending to server, other fields are for UI usage. Presently I clone objects by manually creating assignments for each field, that result in rather not nice structures, as shown below. Note that I would keep field names identical for parts being copied.

```
var contData = {
                ContainerType: data.ContainerType,
                ProjectIds: data.ProjectIds,
                PrivateToProjects: data.PrivateToProjects,
                DimensionType:data.DimensionType,
                MetricsX: data.MetricsX,
                MetricsY: data.MetricsY,
                Parent:data.Parent,
                ContainerName:data.Prefix
            };
```

What would be the best way to code cloning part of object, just specifying list of fields to clone/not to clone, such as some useful helper function?

I also use angular and jquery.

Comment: Yes. Have you tried writing such a helper function? It's quite trivial actually. I don't think there already is one in angular or jquery.

Answer (score 10):

After ES6, you could

```
let { ContainerType, ProjectIds } = data  // the fields you want
let partiallyCopy = { ContainerType, ProjectIds }
console.log(partiallyCopy)  // { ContainerType: "...", ProjectIds: "..." }
```

And if you need most fields, you could

```
let { ContainerType, ProjectIds, ...rest } = data  // the fields you don't want
let partiallyCopy = rest
console.log(partiallyCopy)  // the object excludes ContainerType and ProjectIds
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a custom function to clone your object partially with a filter function.

It could be something like this as the very simple version.

```
function filteredClone(sourceObj, filterFunction){
  var destObj = {};
  for(var i in sourceObj){
    if(filterFunction(sourceObj[i])){
      destObj[i] = sourceObj[i];
    }
  }
  return destObj;
}
```

And you can call it like the following assuming that you don't want "name" and "surname" fields to be copied.

```
var dest = filteredClone(source, function(v){
   return ["name","surname"].indexOf(v) !== -1;
});
```

There are a couple of more sophisticated samples in the answers to the following question.

[Deep clone without some fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14275467/deep-clone-without-some-fields)

Answer (score 0):

Dan's destructuring [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50965203/2571805) is good, but it still requires an assignment, making it less than ideal (however still possible) for lambda, or arrow-style, concatenation. It remains a great way to filter out object fields when passing parameters to a functions, for instance

Here's an alternative that you can embed in an expression and that doesn't use assignment side-effects:

```js
wanted = ['ContainerType', 'ProjectIds', 'PrivateToProjects',
         'DimensionType', 'MetricsX', 'MetricsY', 'Parent', 'Prefix']

contData = Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(data).filter(x => wanted.includes(x[0]))))
```

The only state this requires is the `wanted` fields. If you want to preserve most fields in `data`, you can always use `notWanted` instead and negate the `filter` condition.

Answer (score -1):

One method is to define properties on objects.  IE9 is the first IE to support this.

```
var obj = {};
Object.defineProperty(obj, "no1", {enumerable: false, value: "", writable: true, configurable: true});
Object.defineProperty(obj, "no2", {enumerable: false, value: "", writable: true, configurable: true});

obj.yes1 = "foo";
obj.yes2 = "bar";
obj.no1 = "baz";
obj.no2 = "quux";
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pcG5F/)

99.9% of clone functions will loop over the keys, and only enumerable keys will show up, so they only copy enumerable keys.  This is the same reason why, e.g. `toString` doesn't show up when looping over an object's keys.

This can be abstracted to allow defining data and temporary values.

```
function makeType(description, data) {
    if (arguments.length === 1) {
        return function (data) {
            return makeType.call(this, description, data);
        };
    }

    var obj = {};
    data = data || {};
    for (var key in description) {
        if (description[key] === true) {
            obj[key] = data[key]
        } else {
            Object.defineProperty(obj, key, {
                enumerable: false,
                value: data[key],
                writable: true,
                configurable: true
            });
        }
    }
    return obj;
}

var makeYesNo = makeType({
    yes1: true,
    yes2: true,
    no1: false,
    no2: false
});

var obj = makeYesNo({
    yes1: "foo",
    yes2: "bar",
    no1: "baz",
    no2: "quux"
})
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5AKXt/)